# Passing (partially) templated template function as std::function(or function pointer)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, function-templates

```c++
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

template<class F>
class Foo
{
public:
    template <class T>
    void std_function(std::function<F(std::vector<T>)> functor)
    {
        /* something */
    }

    template <class T>
    void func_ptr(F (*funtor)(std::vector<T>))
    {
        /* something else */
    }
};

template<class T, class F>
F bar(std::vector<T>)
{
    return F();
}

int main()
{
    Foo<double> test;
    std::function<double(std::vector<int>)> barz = bar<int, double>;

    test.std_function(bar<int, double>); //error 1
    test.std_function(barz); //OK 1
    test.func_ptr(bar<int, double>); //OK 2

    test.std_function(bar<int>); //error 2::1
    test.func_ptr(bar<int>); //error 2::2

    return 0;
}
```

**Question 1.**

Line *error 1* : I am trying to pass explicitly instantiated template function(`bar<int, double>`) as `std::function`, but It is not legal.

Line *OK 1* : If I wrap `bar<int, double>` into `std::function<double(std::vector<int>)>` and pass wrapped functor, it is legal now.

Line *OK 2* : If I pass `bar<int, double>` through `Foo::func_ptr`, which gets function pointer as argument instead of `std::function`, it is also legal.

I want to make the Line *error 1* legal. As in the Line *OK 2*, it is possible to pass `bar<int, double>` without any wrapper(unlike Line *OK 1*) and keep same form. But, the parameter type is different. I want to pass as `std::function`, not function pointer.

**Question 2.**

Line *error 2::1 and 2::2* : What I am trying to achieve here is, I want class `Foo` to deduce return type of `bar` as its class template type `F`(for the code above, `F` is `double`). So I can just pass as `bar<int>`, not `bar<int, double>`.

But It seems to fail deduction, because even if I pass `bar<int>` through `Foo::func_ptr`, it still produces error. How can I make this code work as my intention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For error 1, what's happening is that the compiler is attempting to substitute for `T` in `std::function`, but it cannot because ultimately a function pointer and a `std::function` are different types, and there's no conversion defined for a function pointer to `std::function`

This worked:

```
std::function<double(std::vector<int>)> barz = bar<int, double>
```

Because `std::function` was cleverly written with type-erasure to have a constructor that can accept any callable that is convertible to the type it needs. Note that this isn't the same as type-deduction in the above error because here we are already specifying the template arguments for `std::function`.

Note that we can do a little work to get `Foo::std_function` to work properly. First change its signature to take a forwarding reference:

```
template <class T>
void std_function(T&& functor){/*I'll talk about this in a bit*\}
```

Then we can construct our `std::function` internally (What you're looking to pass into it, I don't know) by using some helper structs to determine its type. For a function pointer we can do the following:

```
// base
template<class... T>
struct function_type_impl;

// specialization for function ptrs and static class fns
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct function_type_impl<Ret(*)(Args...)>
{
   using type = std::function<Ret(Args...)>;
};

// type alias so we don't need to keep typing typename ... ::type
template<class... T>
using function_type = typename function_type_impl<std::decay_t<T>...>::type;
```

and then we can modify our `std_function` signature:

```
template <class T>
void std_function(T&& functor)
{
    function_type<T> myFunction = std::forward<T>(functor);
    // do something with our std::function
}
```

Then you can call it as

```
test.std_function(&::bar<int, double>);
```

However, if we want to be more complete, and accept functors, lambdas, and even other `std::functions`, we can add more specializations:

```
namespace detail
{
template<class... T>
struct function_type_impl;

template<class Callable>
struct function_type_impl<Callable>
{
    using type = typename function_type_impl<decltype(&Callable::operator())>::type;
};

template<class C, class Ret, class... Args>
struct function_type_impl<Ret(C::*)(Args...) const>
{
    using type = std::function<Ret(Args...)>;
};

template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct function_type_impl<Ret(*)(Args...)>
{
    using type = std::function<Ret(Args...)>;
};

template<class... T>
using function_type = typename function_type_impl<std::decay_t<T>...>::type;
}// detail namespace
```

And now the following will work, too:

```
struct MyFunctor
{
    double operator()(std::vector<int>) const
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

struct MyFunctor2
{
    static double foo(std::vector<int>)
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<double> test;
    std::function<double(std::vector<int>)> barz = bar<int, double>;
    test.std_function(&::bar<int, double>);
    test.std_function(barz);
    test.std_function([](std::vector<int>)->double{return 42;});
    test.std_function(MyFunctor{});
    test.std_function(MyFunctor2::foo);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/CJNLOz6ZwhCBYNmj)

For errors 2::1 and 2::2, the issue is simpler; functions do not exist at all until they're completely instantiated. That is, you cannot create a function pointer to a partially templated function. You have to specify all the template arguments when trying to get a function pointer. Since you have already specified the return type, you can allow the compiler to instantiate the rest of the pointer for you if you explicitly tell `func_ptr` what to deduce for `T`:

```
test.func_ptr<int>(bar);
```

Comment: For paragraph 2: [void counter_example( double(*)(std::vector<int>) );](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb9979b58f3f76e7) -- I can convert a function template into a function pointer without passing any template arguments.

Comment: @Yakk: Huh, I did not know that. Thank you for the learning. Post updated.

Comment: @gear not necessarily. std::function can bind to a wider breadth of things like lambdas. Function pointers will be a little more specific and faster

Comment: Error 1 isn't a non-deduced context. It's a plain deduction failure due to type mismatch.